# Viewing Access 2013 web app DB in Azure

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, azure, ms-access-2013

Does anyone know how access a Access 2013 web app deployed on SharePoint via Azure? I have built an app and the db gets deployed into SQL Azure. I want to have full access to it via Azure. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

After you publish the Access web application, then in the Access client you MUST enable external use. When you enable external use then a user name + password is generated for you. You can then view these values by again view the connections in Access.

These connection strings can be used in Excel, the sql management studio, or even a regular non web Access database. In fact such connection strings should work even for a web site and .net.

So just about anything can connect to these SQL Auzre tables, and the "enabling" of the connections is done from the Access client.

The connection opens are found via

File->and then click on mange connections. You see these options:
[image]